# Dependency Injection for MVC

Tags: java, model-view-controller, dependency-injection, guice, gwt-gin

I know DI is mostly used with MVP pattern however, where does Google Gin fits into a Model-View-Controller framework/pattern?

For example, usually for a MVC a View holds references to the Model (in which it listen to change events) and the Controller holds references to the Model and the View. I mean how I can improve a MVC pattern using DI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DI has nothing to do with MVC or MVP, it's IOC pattern which abstracts the dependencies for cleaners/easier unit testing and decoupling via DI container.

Comment: You have a point however, my question is how I can use DI to enhance the code of my MVC, in MVP pattern its something like this: bindPresenter(LoginPresenter.class, LoginPresenter.MyView.class,
    LoginView.class, LoginPresenter.MyProxy.class);